# SQL group three columns from three tables into one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables x, y, z that have similar columns like this and the other columns are different:

**table x**:

| id | user_id | month | year | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | January | 2023 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 1 | February | 2023 | 200.00 |

**table y**:

| id | user_id | month | year | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | March | 2023 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2 | May | 2023 | 200.00 |

**table z**:

| id | user_id | month | year | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | March | 2023 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 2 | May | 2023 | 200.00 |

And also there is user table:

| user_id | last_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Wick |
| 2 | Bill | Week |

I wrote query but I don't know how to join years and months into one column in result:

```
select u.user_id, sum(x.total_price + y.total_price + z.total_price), x.month, y.month, z.month x.year, y.year, z.year     
from user u 
join x x on u.user_id = x.user_id join y y on u.user_id = y.user_id 
join z z on u.user_id = z.user_id 
group by u.user_id, x.month, y.month, z.month, x.year, y.year, z.year;
```

So, I want to achieve that to join all three tables into one and sum total price per user_id, month and year:

| user_id | month | year | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 2023 | 100.00 |
| 1 | February | 2023 | 200.00 |
| 1 | March | 2023 | 200.00 |
| 2 | May | 2023 | 400.00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all the table and try this.

```
SELECT u.user_id, 
       month,
       year,
       SUM(total_price) AS total_price
FROM user u
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM y
  UNION ALL
  SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM z
) AS combined
ON u.user_id = combined.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, month, year
ORDER BY u.user_id, year, month;
```

Comment: this is what I want to achieve, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

You want a union based approach followed by an aggregation:

```sql
SELECT user_id, month, year, SUM(total_price) AS total_price
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM z
) t
GROUP BY user_id, month, year
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine rows from your tables and then perfom aggregation here is an example:

**SQL**

```
SELECT user_id, month, year, SUM(total_price) AS total_price
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM x
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM y
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_id, month, year, total_price FROM z
    ) AS CombinedData
    GROUP BY user_id, month, year
    ORDER BY user_id, year, month;
```

[image]